# How does David maintain a secret cabin in the ship without any human knowing about it?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-covenant

In the final scene of *Alien: Covenant* (2017), David owns this cabin
which contains alien embryos & some humans in hypersleep.
[image: Man walking down corridor between rows of hypersleep chambers]

How does David maintain a secret cabin in the ship without any human knowing about it?

Comment: Is it secret? Isn’t it just the hyper sleep chamber where the other colonists were?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Paul D. Waite's comment, and confirmed by [the script directions](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/uploads/scripts/alien-covenant-2017.pdf), this is the ship nursery, nothing secret.

> INT. COVENANT-NURSERY
>   The gentle snow falls.
>   David strides in.
>   The Colonists. Tier after tier after tier of them in
>   hypersleep.
>   Also the rows of embryos.

What is secret is what he is hiding [among the other embryos](https://youtu.be/vKyhS-23NOc):

> He coughs up two Xenomorph embryos and puts them in a sample tray with the human embryos.

In the original shooting script, it was instead within the Wardroom.

> INT. COVENANT-WARDROOM
>  The Wagner continues as he enters.
>  He goes to the vertical garden that soars up along one wall.
>  To a growth of ferns. Kneels and looks beneath them. Smiles.
>  A neat little row of three very small ALIEN EGGS.

Comment: Were the eggs present in the final film or just in the screenplay/script?

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701: You're right. They apparently changed that.